# How to properly register a file extension on mac so it will also work by running open from the command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, file-extensions

I have the following problem, I registered a file extension to be opened by a Mac Application by clicking on the file in Finder and selecting to always use the target application to open the files.

So far it works, BUT it doesn't work with `>open filename.ext` as it will say:

```
No application knows how to open /path/filename.ext.
```

Clearly `open` works differently than Finder.

If possible I would prefer a command line solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you selected Always Open With from a context menu, it only changes the default application for the selected items. If you change the default application from an information window, it normally also has an immediate effect on `open`.

If it wasn't that, com.apple.LaunchServices.plist can also be edited as XML:

```
plutil -convert xml1 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist
```

Applying changes requires restarting. Logging out and back in isn't enough.

You could also try using [duti](http://duti.org/) or [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/).

Answer (score 0):

You can add them to the `LaunchServices.plist` file. To do that you open the `.plist` (I did it in XCode, if you've not got XCode installed there's standalone packages you can get), then you add a new tag entry with the application and extension you want. You'll have a fair few already in there that you can reference.

In theory what you set in Finder should be honoured by Terminal and `open`, but if it's not then it might be something in `LaunchServices` not working correctly.

Comment: Where is this file located on OS X 10.8? `locate` does not seem to find it.

Comment: It can be found in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`, sorry I completely forgot to add that.